# how to isolate a single database on shared hosting with MS SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

this is not a code question but rather a connection question.

I have NetworkSolutions as a hosting provide.

I'm using SQL Server Management studio to access.

When I connect and click databases I literally see THOUSANDS... I want to isolate just MY database.

What additional connection parameters do I need to do that?

Thanks

Comment: There isn't a way to prevent that. When you login with SSMS it shows all databases in the list of databases, even if you don't currently have access. Also, you don't setup the connection string in SSMS, it is is built by the tool using the parameters you provide. Hopefully your user has your database as the default.

Comment: I'm the user and admin for the database on the account.  The default DB is set, (ie - Initial Catalog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same with Plesk Admin shared hosting account where there are hundreds of databases. Listing all of them first to find the one you need can be time consuming. To fix this: -

1. Log into SSMS
2. BEFORE you expand the databases node, right click on Databases-->Filter-->Filter settings as illustrated[image: filter databases].
3. Enter your database name as illustrated[image: enter database name]. Then click OK
4. At this point, click the (+) sign to expand the (FILTERED) Database node.